# Unable to create files/folders using php on Apache Web-Server

Tags: php, apache, permissions, webserver

> touch(): unable to create file /var/www/html/test.txt because Permission denied in /var/www/html/web_services/test.php on line 6.

The php script in question

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    echo exec("whoami");
    touch("/var/www/html/test.txt");
?>
```

Development environment is rhel8. I have tried setting the ownership to apache:apache with.

> sudo chown -R apache:apache www

I even tried with setting permissions as `777` to the entire `www` directory recursively with

> sudo chmod -R 777 www

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: PResumably the folder `/var/www/html` is not writable for the apache user (and that is good so - php should *never* be allowed to write in document root)

Comment: Assuming your site is in `/var/www/` the try `touch("html/test.txt");` or if it lives in `/var/www/html`  then try `touch("test.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type

`sudo chmod a+wr /var/www/html`
Type your password

You're done.

Comment: If answer doesn't work do this, change ownership from root to user `chown $(whoami):$(whoami) /var/www/html`